# C++ - Visual Studio - missing type specifier - int assumed

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
class Space2D {
public:
    vector<Agent> v;
    bool star;

    Space2D() {
        bool star = false;
    }
};
```

In visual studio this give me a error: missing type specifier - int assumed. I also get errors like syntax error: missing ';' before '<'.

`std::vector<Agent> v;` Solved this

Comment: Have you defined Agent anywhere? Is the h-file where it is defined included?

Comment: 1. useful to know which line the error is referring to. 2. your code is not compileable outside of your machine as it's not complete.

Comment: Didn't you forget to `#include "Agent.h" #include <vector>`?

Comment: @EdChum Apparently it's not compilable inside his machine either :D

Comment: @GillBates true, Jan please send your machine to me so I can have a look at this

Comment: additionally to @SingerOfTheFall, use `std::vector`

Comment: The line vector<Agent> give me this error. And i have both include's.

Comment: Do you also have a `using namespace std;` before this code? (Although I personally prefer to write `std::vector` instead of `vector`)

Comment: I recommend "using std::vector;", this will allow one to omit the namespace parts and will still allow one to see where vector comes from and avoids name collisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possible problems with this code.

1. Possibly `vector` header is not included

Fix: `#include <vector>`

2. Possibly Agent class is not defined

Fix: include header, where Agent class is defined

3. Possibly you forgot to write `using namespace std;` as **wrongly** recommended by beginner books

Fix: instead of 'vector' on line 7 use `std::vector`, or do it wrong and write `using namespace std;`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot std:: before vector.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from two error messages you posted and by guessing to which line they correspond to you forget to `#include <vector>` or you do not have imported `std::vector` to your namespace (`using std::vector;` or `using namespace std`).

I personally would not recommend using either of those `using`s for [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and instead wrote `std::vector`.